# edit list collection problem : error note Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following classes:

```
Product, Service and OrderItem
```

`Product` and `Service` must inherit `OrderItem`. So basically I want to store `OrderItem` object in my shopping cart and these object are store in a list.

```
Public MustInherit Class OrderItem
    Private m_enuItemType As TypeOfItem = TypeOfItem.None
    Private m_strUserID As Integer
    Private m_UserName As String
    Private m_Currency As String
    Private m_CurrencyType As Decimal
    Private m_MiniCartSubTotal As Decimal

    Public Sub New(ByVal enuItemType As TypeOfItem)
        m_enuItemType = enuItemType
    End Sub

    Public Enum TypeOfItem
        None = 0
        Product = 1
        Service = 2
    End Enum

    Public Property ItemType() As TypeOfItem
        Get
            Return m_enuItemType
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As TypeOfItem)
            m_enuItemType = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Class Product**

```
Public Class CartProduct
    Inherits OrderItem

    Private Product_Id As String = ""
    Private Qty As Integer = Nothing
    Private price As String = ""
    Private priceFormat As String = ""
    Private UserPrice As Decimal = 0

    Public Sub New(ByVal enuItemType As TypeOfItem)
        MyBase.New(enuItemType)
    End Sub

    Public Property ProductId() As String
        Get
            Return Product_Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Product_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Here is my problem:** When user add product, I want to verify if the product already exist in the List. If it does, I want to increment the value but I'm having an error. Here is my add orderItem code:

```
Public Function AddItem(ByVal objOrderItem As OrderItem) As Boolean

    Try

        If m_objArrListOfItems.Count > 0 Then

         ' Validate item to check if it is already in the list
        ' If yes, increment counter, otherwise add new item to the list

            Dim objValidateCartProduct As New CartProduct(OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product)
            Select Case objOrderItem.ItemType
                Case OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product
                    objValidateCartProduct = DirectCast(objOrderItem, CartProduct)
            End Select


            For Each p As CartProduct In m_objArrListOfItems
                If objValidateCartProduct.ProductId = p.ProductId Then
                    p.OrderQty = p.OrderQty + objValidateCartProduct.OrderQty

                Else
                    m_objArrListOfItems.Add(objOrderItem)
                End If

            Next


        Else
            m_objArrListOfItems.Add(objOrderItem)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        ' Log error
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use a for loop for this kind of stuff. I haven't tested this code, but it should go something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_objArrListOfItems.Count; i++)
{
    Product p = m_objArrListOfItems[i];
    if (objValidateCartProduct.ProductID == p.ProductID)
    {
        p.OrderQty += objValidateCartProduct.OrderQty;
        break;
    }
    m_objArrListOfItems.Add(objOrderItem);        
}
```

VB.NET

**EDIT**: Changed `Continue For` to `Exit For` when a matching `ProductID` is found.

It sounds like you need to break out of the loop when a matching `ProductID` is found, so try this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To m_objArrListOfItems.Count - 1
    Dim p As Product = m_objArrListOfItems(i)
    If objValidateCartProduct.ProductID = p.ProductID Then
        p.OrderQty += objValidateCartProduct.OrderQty
        Exit For
    End If
    m_objArrListOfItems.Add(objOrderItem)        
Next
```

Comment: thank for your reply code is working but im having  a slight problem when i click on first product it add and keep increment they quantiy but however when i add second product it does increment it and keep adding one extrac record

Comment: I assume that's happening because the second `ProductID` doesn't match `objValidateCartProduct.ProductID`. What should be happening in that case?

Comment: i try an if else condition im still geting same result

Comment: It sounds like you need to check the `ProductID` against `objOrderItem` rather than `objValidateCartProduct`

Comment: i need to cast product in objOrderItem ( objValidateCartProduct = DirectCast(objOrderItem, CartProduct) because i cant used objOrderItem

Comment: Okay, then see the last code block in my answer. I think that should work. You need to exit the For loop when a match is found.

Comment: it giving me same result with exit, continue or if else condition loop what happen it check the ProductID  then it loop if the ProductId dont exit it goes on the next then it add a new record

Comment: Is it making it into the `If` condition? Can you edit your question and include the updated code?

Comment: i able to slove it i dont know im im using the right approach in the loop when there is a match i add this object in a new arraylist then manipulate they object there